# Upgrade curl to latest on CentOS 6.3

Tags: centos, curl

Thought this would be a simple process, but I guess not. I need the latest version of CURL (7.23 or newer) on CentOS 6.3.

If I do this:

> sudo yum upgrade curl

It just tells me there is nothing to do (everything is up to date).

So I followed some other ServerFault posts, and tried this:

> sudo rpm -i http://mirror.city-fan.org/ftp/contrib/sysutils/Mirroring/libcurl-7.29.0-2.0.cf.rhel6.x86_64.rpm

But that tells me:

> warning: /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.4L8Nyj: Header V3 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID
>   b56a8bac: NOKEY error: Failed dependencies:
>           c-ares(x86-64) >= 1.9.1 is needed by libcurl-7.29.0-2.0.cf.rhel6.x86_64
>           libssh2(x86-64) >= 1.4.3 is needed by libcurl-7.29.0-2.0.cf.rhel6.x86_64

So what do I actually have to do to get this upgraded?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The package you want to install need dependencies which aren't in standart repositories. Use "city-fan.org" repo for these dependencies: http://www.city-fan.org/ftp/contrib/yum-repo/ And install it with yum command.

It should be something like this:

```
rpm -Uvh http://www.city-fan.org/ftp/contrib/yum-repo/city-fan.org-release-1-12.rhel6.noarch.rpm
yum install libcurl
```

Answer (score 2):

Try executing these commands:

```
rpm -Uvh http://www.city-fan.org/ftp/contrib/yum-repo/city-fan.org-release-1-12.rhel6.noarch.rpm
yum install libcurl
```

And restart your Apache afterwards.

```
service httpd restart
```

Run `phpinfo()` and it will show new curl version.