# Upgrade curl to latest on CentOS 7

Tags: centos7, curl

I need to upgrade cURL on my VPS running CentOS 7.

I'm gettings errors as:

```
cURL Error(35): Cannot communicate securely with peer: no common encryption algorithm(s)
```

I've used the answer given here before: [Upgrade curl to latest on CentOS 6.3](https://serverfault.com/questions/485227/upgrade-curl-to-latest-on-centos-6-3/)
But the link to the RPM file is dead and I don't know which to choose from the list on the [yum-repo page](http://www.city-fan.org/ftp/contrib/yum-repo/).

Help on how to upgrade curl highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31107851/how-to-fix-curl-35-cannot-communicate-securely-with-peer-no-common-encryptio ?

Comment: Don't use "the answer given here before". It does not apply to your system.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. The current version installed is: cURL Information 7.29.0

Comment: By the way, what you did to get this error ?

Comment: I moved InfiniteWP (iWP) to a new server. It connects to WordPress sites remotely. Well, not any more. And also an error grabbing mails from a imap inbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting a comment from @Peps:

> Upgrading cURL 7.42.1 helped me with this issue previously. Would this work: `rpm -Uvh http://www.city-fan.org/ftp/contrib/yum-repo/rhel6/x86_64/city-fan.org-release-1-13.rhel6.noarch.rpm
>   yum install libcurl`

This will work on CentOS 6.7 in a safe way and it should be the accepted answer.
Basically, it adds a third-party repo where someone compiled cURL 7.42 and its dependencies, keeping CentOS package names, so `yum` will recognize and install them as upgrade for the legacy curl package without breaking any dependence.

Tried it on a CentOS 6.7 server + Plesk 12.5

Comment: Repo no longer available

Comment: **WARNING** City-fan is a *Known Problem Repository* per [the CentOS wiki](https://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories) : "Be **particularly careful** about the City-Fan repo as they enable their repo by default when installed. City-Fan **will** replace many core packages as configured when installed and those packages often have a different structure than the CentOS ones making them difficult if not impossible to remove cleanly. Even **removing** packages installed from this repository may leave the system in an unusable state. You've been warned."

Answer (score 3):

There is a known bug in fedora for nss which causes similar problem with curl. See  [NSS does not enable ECC cipher-suites by default](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1185708.).  Its about some default support for ECC cipher-suit.

Check if your version of nss is also affected. Then you can possibly upgrade.

You can try as suggested in the thread:

```
curl -4svo/dev/null --ciphers ecdhe_ecdsa_aes_128_gcm_sha_256 https://www.example.org
```

or simply,

```
curl --ciphers ecdhe_ecdsa_aes_256_sha https://www.example.org
```

Another option is to upgrade to `curl-7.43.0-1.el7` and  try. RPMs are available here: http://cbs.centos.org/koji/buildinfo?buildID=1408

- Go to the link and download the rpms to local hard disks. Then you can use `rpm` command to upgrade or install the packages that you need.

  1. curl-7.43.0-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
  2. libcurl-7.43.0-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
  3. libcurl-devel-7.43.0-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
  4. curl-debuginfo-7.43.0-1.el7.x86_64.rpm

  **I haven't tried it myself, so try it with your own risk.**

Comment: Ok, so i should run that command in ssh. This is a live server, that won't be a problem? How will i know if i'm affected? I'll receive an error? (I'm new to this)

Comment: cURL collect url, so try on one of your server safely

Comment: Result: About to connect() to www.example.org port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 93.184.216.34...
* Connected to www.example.org (93.184.216.34) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
* Unknown cipher in list: ecdhe_ecdsa_aes_128_gcm_sha_256
* Closing connection 0

Comment: Try the second option in the answer and run curl with the `-v` option. The answer indicates to mention explicitly the cipher suite to be used in the curl command option.

Comment: Sorry, i don't know what you mean exactly. Where should i add the -v option?

Comment: Upgrading cURL 7.42.1 helped me with this issue previously. Would this work: rpm -Uvh http://www.city-fan.org/ftp/contrib/yum-repo/rhel6/x86_64/city-fan.org-release-1-13.rhel6.noarch.rpm
yum install libcurl

Comment: Can't tell you for sure. I guess not, it meant for rhel6.

Comment: Try the ones here: http://cbs.centos.org/koji/buildinfo?buildID=1408

Comment: That looks like it :) Could you maybe share the install command with me so i won't mess-up?

Comment: See updated answer. Download those rpms and  try with `rpm -Uvh`.

Comment: Thanks! I must download all 4(?) with rpm -Uvh, then run "yum install...."?

Comment: And what about this: http://curl.haxx.se/download.html ?

Comment: I did: yum install libcurl-7.43.0-1.el7.x86_64.rpm and I got an error: Finished Dependency Resolution
Error:  Multilib version problems found. This often means that the root
       cause is something else and multilib version checking is just
       pointing out that there is a problem.

Comment: What do you think about the solution offered in the last 2 comments here: https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=53917

Comment: You can try it, looks good.

Comment: So maybe this rpm could solve the issue safely?http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/updates/19/x86_64/libcurl-7.29.0-27.fc19.x86_64.rpm What you think, is this safe to try?

Comment: These are from fedoraproject, you can safely try.

Comment: @bangal, would this be the way to go: wget http://mirror.fdcservers.net/fedora/updates/19/x86_64/libcurl-7.29.0-27.fc19.x86_64.rpm
yum install libcurl-7.29.0-27.fc19.x86_64.rpm ?

Comment: I get an error when i try it like this: Protected multilib versions: libcurl-7.29.0-19.el7.i686 != libcurl-7.29.0-27.fc19.x86_64 should i try a different method of installing?

Comment: Could someone advise on how to install the rpm?

Answer (score 1):

1) `nano /etc/yum.repos.d/city-fan.repo`

2) ADD:

```
[CityFan]
name=City Fan Repo
baseurl=http://www.city-fan.org/ftp/contrib/yum-repo/rhel$releasever/$basearch/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
```

3)

```
yum clean all
yum install curl
```

Comment: **WARNING** City-fan is a *Known Problem Repository* per [the CentOS wiki](https://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories) : "Be particularly careful about the City-Fan repo as they enable their repo by default when installed. City-Fan will replace many core packages as configured when installed and those packages often have a different structure than the CentOS ones making them difficult if not impossible to remove cleanly. Even removing packages installed from this repository may leave the system in an unusable state. You've been warned."